# How to add ethereum-based token to my app?

Tags: web3js, erc-20, testnets

I am new to this erea and I am trying to write a wallet application.
I have developed my wallet to publish on `Ethereum` and can now publish to ETH `mainnet`.
I am wondering if I can add some more coins to my wallet app which are compatible to this chain, since they don't need much development, like Shiba which is a smart contract on ETH network.

Now, my question is, how can I find more coins like Shiba which are developed and work well on ETH network? and how can I find a `testnet` to check my development for those coins? (How to setup a development environment for those coins?)

Thanks,

Comment: From the title it sound like you're planning to develop your own token, but the body of the question asks about finding existing ones. I suggest editing the tittle.

Comment: @kfx Thank you for your useful suggestion. I made the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a [list of tokens in the Ethereum ecosystem here](https://www.coingecko.com/en/categories/ethereum-ecosystem) or in [TokenList](https://tokenlists.org/)

Comment: Thank you Antonio, Can you add details about sample implementations to complete the answer?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what you need exactly. Any ERC20 token will work with your app as long as you use the methods from [the standard API](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20), like `balanceOf` or `transfer`. [Here's an article](https://chainstack.com/ultimate-guide-erc20-token-balance/) I wrote a few weeks ago that explains how to retrieve balances, which I think could be helpful